# why 'remoteCertificate' parameter is empty in LocalCertificateSelectionCallback method?

Tags: .net, ssl

i wanna setup a SSL connection, but really don't know everything about SSL handshake rules and life cycle. i wrote a code

```
void main()
{
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.160", 4113);
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(localCertSelection)
                );
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
}

public X509Certificate localCertSelection(object sender, string targetHost, X509CertificateCollection localCertificates, X509Certificate remoteCertificate, string[] acceptableIssuers)
        {// why here 'remoteCertificate' parameter is empty? 'acceptableIssuers' and 'localCertificates' too
            string cert = "MIIEwjCCA6qgAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w...";
            X509Certificate clientCert = new X509Certificate(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cert));
            return clientCert;
        }

public bool ValidateServerCertificate(
              object sender,
              X509Certificate certificate,
              X509Chain chain,
              SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
// 'certificate' has data now. it has come from server
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

            // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
            return false;
        }
```

when i run the code, program flow first goes to 'localCertSelection' method and then goes to 'ValidateServerCertificate' method.
in 'localCertSelection' method 'remoteCertificate' is empty , but in 'ValidateServerCertificate' method 'certificate' has data. it has come from server, but why 
'sslPolicyErrors' is 'RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | RemoteCertificateChainErrors' ?
what's wrong? what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

The `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch` error may occur if your "servername" are wrong. I mean that servername in

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
```

must be "192.168.1.160", the same as in

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.160", 4113);
```

The `RemoteCertificateChainErrors` happen if something wrong with your root certificate. When you create certificate you have to put appropriate host in CN,
CN=192.168.1.160. And don't forget import your root certificate to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".